# React Native card images doesn't render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making a react native project with a carousel and bunch of cards
I managed to add texts to the cards but can't add images to them 
here is my code

```
 constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slider1ActiveSlide: SLIDER_1_FIRST_ITEM,
        GridListItems: [
          { key: "Makeup Artists" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg' },
          { key: "Photographers" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Wedding Halls" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Wedding Planners" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Ateliers for Dresses" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Hotels" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Hair Dresser" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Veil Designers" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Laser & Beauty Centers", img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg' },
          { key: "Dental Clinics" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "Gym & Physical Fitness" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
          { key: "SPA" , img: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'},
        ]
    };
}
```

here is how I render

```
render () {

  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>[![enter image description here][1]][1]

          <View style={styles.container}>

              <StatusBar
                translucent={true}
                backgroundColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}
                barStyle={'light-content'}
              />
              { this.gradient }
              <ScrollView
                style={styles.scrollview}
                scrollEventThrottle={200}
                directionalLockEnabled={true}
                 <FlatList
                  data={ this.state.GridListItems }
                  renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                  <View style={styles.GridViewContainer}>
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: item.img }}
                      style={styles.image}
                    />
                    <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout} onPress={this.GetGridViewItem.bind(this, item.key)} > {item.key} </Text>
                  </View> }
                numColumns={2}
         />
              </ScrollView>

          </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[image]

as you see no images on the cards how can I overcome this problem?

also, I would like to add navigation to each card how can I achieve this too?

Comment: Can you also share the style definitions used in the code

Comment: As per the documentation, it says that for remote Image you need to specify the width and height for the remote image. As you have not shown the styles its unclear.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

Comment: yes you are right i set width and height and the images is shown now but i want it to expand with the card i mean if the card got bigger in diffrent screen the image scale with it how can i do that if i set the height and width with fixed values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `width` and `height` for remote images as said in [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html):

> Note that for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!

Also if you need a scalable size, you can use some 3rd libs like [react-native-responsive-dimensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions)

And about the navigation (assuming that you are using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)), you can add another property to your items like `name: 'test'` and replace the `<View>` with `TouchableOpacity` component like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.GridViewContainer}
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(item.name)}>
...
</TouchableOpacity>
```